# Regular expression to match nine-digit numbers that start with a 1

Tags: regex

I am trying to match 9-digit numbers that start with a 1

```
"/^1[0-9]{9}$/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^1\d{8}/
```

The first number `1` will be your first digit, so the quantifier should be 8.

Comment: you wanna rescan your pattern? What’s with the `8` at the end?

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?=1)\d{9}$⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there any advantage of a positive lookbehind over just matching it (that is, if your regex consuming doesn't apply to you)?

Comment: +1 for the positive assertion, while not a standard, it's nice to find practical uses for them.

Comment: The main advantage is that it says in code what I think it was that was asked for: 9 digits, the first being a 1.  That way you don't have to do extra math.  There is an issue related to non-ASCII digits, but I doubt that is going to come up with your dataset.  Then again, I’m often wrong, so maybe you should be careful to get only ASCII data.

Comment: @elmt: Define “standard”. ☺ POSIX EREs are *so* boring! ☹

Comment: @Alex, it’s a positive look*ahead*, actually. :)

Comment: @tchrist Really? It looks like it is looking behind, to me. But since when did these things make sense?

Comment: @Alex, lookahead assertion is `(?=…)`, lookahead negation is `(?!…)`, lookbehind assertion is `(?<=…)`, and lookbehind negation is `(?<!…)`. These can get tricky to read if they’re clustered too tightly. They can of course nest or stack, too, or be used as the COND clause in a `(?(COND)THEN_PART|ELSE_PART)`. For example, a `\b` before something is really `(?(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<!\W))`, whereas a `\b` after something is really `(?(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?!\W))`. Neat, eh? Those’d be a tad easier to read in `/x` mode (or `(?x)`, if you prefer).

Comment: @Mike, I keep looking at your lookbehind as though it has emoticons in it. :)

Comment: @Alex, the one that trips people up because it looks like a lookaround but isn’t is `(?>…)` for an independent subgroup. It works like a `(?:…)` that doesn’t ever change its mind on backtracking. Sometimes this is called a grabby or possessive match. You might know it better as the `*+`, `++`, `?+`, `{N,M}+` set, but those are just grabby quantifiers applying to the previous ‘atom’, but `(?>…)` can have anything at all there in the ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

The space is \s

Answer (score 1):

If you need 9 numbers starting with one then you only need to limit the *repetition* of the character class to eight (8):

```
"/^1[0-9]{8}$/"
```

In your sample you have "\ ". If you need to allow spaces use a space or `\s` for whitespace: `[0-9 ]` or `[0-9\s]`.

Comment: Ahmad, technically you are not "limiting the character class", rather you are limiting its *repetition*.  Limiting the character class to 8 would look like `[0-8]` or even just `[8]`. ;-)